# How to write NULL character '\0' to a text file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have to write some data to a text file, and at the end of each output I have to append a NULL terminating character '\0'. Currently this is what I have come up so far. It works well for some inputs, however for some it sometimes write the whole text file with garbage value. I there a better way to do this?? In my program I have to write some data, store its location on file and use that for some operations. the next write operation starts at address = address + 500;

```
long int address = get_address();
void write_to_file()
{
      fstream pFILE ("my file.txt");
      char * buffer = new char [500];
      cin.getline(buffer,500);
      pFILE.seekp(address);
      pFILE << buffer;
      pFILE.seekp(address + strlen(buffer));
      pFILE << '\0';
      address += 500;
}
```

Comment: Why you need to write '\0' into text file?

Comment: The requirement of placing '\0' values in a text file sounds a bit dubious, fishy. But if you really need to do that, then just open the file in binary mode (and don't use formatted i/o). And take care of platform specific line endings yourself.

Comment: You don't need the second `seekp` call, the position will be correct.

Comment: I think the you have misunderstood the concept of terminating a string with a '\0' character.

Comment: Oh, and you have a memory leak in the function. Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead.

Comment: Actually I have initialized a 15mb text file with spaces. And in order to read the data written in subsequent 500 byte sized blocks I thought it would be better to write '\0' into the file and read upto it.

Comment: When you already do know the size of each block being 500 bytes, what is the terminator for?

Comment: Some blocks contain less than 500 characters. and if i read that buffer, the spaces also get read into the buffer. I only want to read what i first wrote to the file.for example if write this to the file "this is my first post on stackoverflow". the read command read it as"this is my first post on stackoverflow           (and some spaces)". @JensG

Comment: Maybe you need some other format to store the strings with...

Comment: `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant. Don't use the name `NULL` to refer to the null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 3):

To write a '\0' to file:

```
fstream output_file("output_file.txt", ios::binary);
output_file.put('\0');
```

The `ios::binary` prevents the compiler or OS from translating the '\0'.